# Error handling probably not working in php script

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script that goes like:-

```
<?php session_start() ?>

<body>
 <?php 
   try{
      $userId=$_GET['userId'];
   }
   catch(Exception $e){
      $userId=$_SESSION['userId2'];
   }?>
```

with `$userId=$_GET['userId'];` this being my line number 23.

I'm loading the script using `http://localhost/checkIdAbout.php?all=ALL`.

Now clearly my URL doesn't have the value for `$userId`, so it'll give an error and that's understandable to me. What I don't understand is that why isn't the try-catch block coming into play? I already stored the value for `$_SESSION['userId2']`. So shouldn't during execution the code jump from try to catch and give me the required value for `$userId`?

I get the error: `Notice: Undefined index: userId in /var/www/html/checkIdAbout.php on line 23` and I just can't get what's wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: In php Notices and Warnings aren't any Exception use `isset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A notice is not an exception.

You *could* write a custom handler to convert notices to exceptions:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno , $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        return false;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}, E_NOTICE);

try {
    $foo++;
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    echo 'Notice cast to exception: '. $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

... but it's normally a bad idea because throwing an exception interrupts the script flow until next catch (or totally aborts the script if none). And, in this case, I don't think it's justified to intentionally cause a notice just to be able to use exception handling, when there're simpler alternatives, e.g.:

```
$userId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'userId') ?? $_SESSION['userId2'];
```